Engineering Statics

I have attached an image of the question (both parts). In part (a), I found the tension in both cables but could not find the force in the tower AO. I also need help with part (b). Thank you!

Interesting problem.  Is this your homework? I (and others) will be happy to help if you  give us an idea how you are approaching the problem.  This is interesting enough, I think I'll work it out I may even post my work after a few days (after the homework would be due.)

Yes, the homework is past the due date. So, I summed the forces in the x and y directions and found the tensions in cables AB and AC. (1) How do I find the force in tower AO? (2) I am getting a very long equation for AC2 in part b, which makes me feel I am making a mistake.

You should add your attempted solution (including the steps) to the question, so people can pinpoint where you struggle and focus on that part.

to find the compression for in the tower (AO), find the vertical component of all your cables and sum this up.  The tower is the only thing resisting the vertical load of all the cables.

From part A) you have the value (magnitude) and direction of the tension in the cable AC.  For part B you basically have three vectors.  Vector AC where everything is known.  Vector AC1 where direction is known but magnitude is not.  And Vector AC2 where Magnitude is known and Direction is not.  You need to make the sum of Vector AC1 and AC2 equal to vector AC.
